# Package standalone RubyGems for a MacOS app

Tags: ruby, macos, shell, installation

To have the best user experience for my users and to avoid them to install all required packages, I need to package Ruby, RubyGems and some gems packages (pod, xcodeproj) in a MacOS app. I will then use pod and xcodeproj through Command Line inside my MacOS app.

When I try to build ruby from source by specifying a custom installation folder `./configure ---prefix=${FOLDER}`, there are static references to this installation folder in some executables that comes with ruby (including gem).

I tried to change shebang inside those executables by `#!/usr/bin/env ruby` and set my PATH to reference my freshly installed ruby but then I have this error that impact all my configuration:

```
`RubyGems' were not loaded.
`error_highlight' was not loaded.
`did_you_mean' was not loaded.
`syntax_suggest' was not loaded.
```

Do you have any ideas if it is possible to build ruby in full standalone mode and if yes some clues about how to do it ?

Comment: You might look at how Puppet's PDK is packaged. While they're moving to Go, historically it's been Ruby based. You might leverage their approach to PDK packaging, which I'm 99% sure is available as open source.

Answer (score 0):

This is nontrivial to do. A standalone executable is usually called a "statically linked" binary, meaning all of its dependencies were pulled in and bundled into the executable. That way it doesn't need to dynamically load any libraries at runtime and will always run the same on any system with a compatible architecture. In truth there is a spectrum to this: do you statically link *everything*? Even libc? It depends on what you want to do with the resulting binary.

Luckily for you, it looks like someone already did this for Ruby. [Travelling Ruby](https://github.com/phusion/traveling-ruby) provides prebuilt binaries and tools for making custom packages which include gems.

Answer (score 0):

For people who are in the same case, I finally found what's going on.

When moving the newly built ruby folder (which contains bin/lib/include/share), I broke ruby `LOAD_PATH` which is responsible for loading dependencies including rubygems.

Just by setting `RUBYLIB` environment variable that points to the new ruby folder, all problems were resolved.

As an example, by running `ruby -e 'puts $LOAD_PATH'` I got:

```
${OLD_RUBY_FOLDER}/lib/ruby/site_ruby/3.2.0
${OLD_RUBY_FOLDER}/lib/ruby/site_ruby/3.2.0/arm64-darwin22
${OLD_RUBY_FOLDER}/lib/ruby/site_ruby
${OLD_RUBY_FOLDER}/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/3.2.0
${OLD_RUBY_FOLDER}/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/3.2.0/arm64-darwin22
${OLD_RUBY_FOLDER}/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby
${OLD_RUBY_FOLDER}/lib/ruby/3.2.0
${OLD_RUBY_FOLDER}/lib/ruby/3.2.0/arm64-darwin22
```

To fix, I set my `RUBYLIB` environment variable to:

`export RUBYLIB=${NEW_RUBY_FOLDER}/lib/ruby/site_ruby/3.2.0:${NEW_RUBY_FOLDER}/lib/ruby/site_ruby/3.2.0/arm64-darwin22:${NEW_RUBY_FOLDER}/lib/ruby/site_ruby:${NEW_RUBY_FOLDER}/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/3.2.0:${NEW_RUBY_FOLDER}/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/3.2.0/arm64-darwin22:${NEW_RUBY_FOLDER}/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby:${NEW_RUBY_FOLDER}/lib/ruby/3.2.0:${NEW_RUBY_FOLDER}/lib/ruby/3.2.0/arm64-darwin22`

As my goal is call ruby through command line directly from my MacOS app, I just have to configure `RUBYLIB` environment variable in my process to make it work.

Answer (score 0):

If you are considering standalone/self-containing/self-sufficient package here follow some references:

- review of legacy/outdate technology https://github.com/tamatebako/tebako.org/files/10418783/post-1.pdf
- overview of the latest available solution https://github.com/tamatebako/tebako.org/files/10831181/post-2.pdf
- the packager https://github.com/tamatebako/tebako